# open a viewcontroller from storyboard when receive apple pushnotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, push-notification

i am developing a app that has a storyboard with 3 view controllers and app in push notification enabled. and when i receive a push notification and when i tap on notification alert it should open a second view controller from my storyboard let me show my code.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

}
```

and then storyboard loads which is actually my first view controller which also have a button in it to second view controller and that is the controller i want to load. and here is the code in my first view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushNotificationReceived) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];
}
-(void)pushNotificationReceived{
    NSString * storyboardName = @"DealerMainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DealerBuyRequests"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

so when i receive notification with this code app crashes when i tap on notification.

Comment: And where's your problem?

Comment: app crashes with this code when it gets pushnotification and i tap on notification.

Comment: What's your error log?

Comment: i am checking it on adhoc production ipa file so how can i get error log in that?

Comment: Maybe on the console?

Comment: No one will be able to answer your question without more information. There are many different things that cause crashes which may not even be related to the code you provided. What does the console say? Is "DealerMainStoryboard" a valid storyboard?

Comment: well yes DealerMainStoryboard is a valid storyboard.

Comment: @user2966615 do you still need help was my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21915200/1880431) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some error log but check this.

```
UIViewController * vc = 
       [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DealerBuyRequests"];
```

I don't think you want to create a new `UIViewController` , unless you really named your controller "**UIViewController**".

So check again the class name of the View you want to present modally

```
DealerBuyRequestsViewController * vc = 
       [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DealerBuyRequests"];
```

Make sure the `StoryBoard Id` of this View controller matches `DealerBuyRequests` or you will get errors.